# Jquery Datatable in Angular 2 Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatable

I'm trying to import Metronic datatable in my angular 2 app, I import all the script and reference (with the html tag `<script>..</script>` and `<link>`) in the main html page, the same where I initialize angular 2 (with `System.import()`..), but it don't work, it show me the table without the search/reordering feature. 
Any advice? How can I import these in angular 2?
Thanks in advance

```
<script src="/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script> 

<link href="/theme2/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/theme2/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/theme2/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme2/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/theme2/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import library in **.angular-cli.json** file

```
{
"scripts": [/themes/..*.js],
}
```

Also , make sure if the library can be installed using **npm install** package.

Comment: Thank you, i don't have any angular-cli.json, should i use it?

Comment: How did u create your app ? Standard method is using angular-cli and npm environments.

Comment: I use the quickstart guide in angular https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html , now i notice that it was a angular-cli quickstart, but i didn't know what it was.

Comment: Good . then the  **.angular-cli.json** will be present in  your app root folder

Comment: No, i started with https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/eplnkr.html this example, without angular-cli.